# MLPRegressor result

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, keyerror

This is an example of a book that I can't figure out or make it work. Other cases I could solve but it became a challenge.
When I run it, it shows me this message:
Paste complete output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\BAULO\PYTHON\ESTRUCTURAS\P_ML\UNIDAD6\Book16.py", line 14, in <module>
    data_y = msu_df[w]
  File "C:\Users\Mauri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3810, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns._get_indexer_strict(key, "columns")[1]
  File "C:\Users\Mauri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 6111, in _get_indexer_strict
    self._raise_if_missing(keyarr, indexer, axis_name)
  File "C:\Users\Mauri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 6171, in _raise_if_missing
    raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Index([('N_Applications',)], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

The csv can be downloaded from: https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Hands-On-Data-Preprocessing-in-Python/blob/main/Chapter06/MSU%20applications.csv

I tried `axis=1` and `reshape`, but I can't figure out the error. I know this topic has already been discussed but what I found doesn't work for me either.

```
import  pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor

msu_df = pd.read_csv('MSU applications.csv')
msu_df.set_index('Year', drop=True, inplace=True)

X = ['P_Football_Performance','SMAn2']
y = 'N_Applications'

w = np.reshape(y, (1,-1))

data_X = msu_df[X]
data_y = msu_df[w]

mlp = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=6, max_iter=100000)
print(mlp.predict(mlp.fit(data_X, data_y)))
```

Comment: Full error message, please.  Looks more like a pandas issue than a numpy one.  Correct the tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing an unnecessary step here:

```
w = np.reshape(y, (1,-1))
```

I'm not sure why you are doing it but that step is just converting `y` from a `string` to an `array`. You can directly pass `y` to get the `label` from the dataframe `msu_df`:

```
y = 'N_Applications'
data_y = msu_df[y]
```

**Additional**: You are calling the `predict()` method on top of `fit()` method which is **not** the [correct way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56518763/model-fit-vs-model-predict-differences-usage-in-sklearn) to make a prediction. The `fit()` method is essentially the training stage and the data used in this stage is the training data which in this case your `data_X` and `data_y`. You would want to make predictions on unseen/new data, not on the ones where the model is already trained. You should replace this line:

```
print(mlp.predict(mlp.fit(data_X, data_y)))
```

with this:

```
mlp.fit(data_X, data_y)
```

Sample code for prediction from the [tutorial notebook](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Hands-On-Data-Preprocessing-in-Python/blob/main/Chapter06/Chapter%206.ipynb) you are following:

```
newData = pd.DataFrame({'P_Football_Performance':0.364,'SMAn2':17198},
                   index=[2022]) 
mlp.predict(newData)
```

Comment: Work. Thanks. but...If I don't use fit() before the estimator I get an error.
I have to study the code. Thank you again.